# PHP code to export to excel specific filtered date

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel, date-range

I am trying to write a simple PHP code to export to excel the data selected between two dates. On clicking the 'Export to Excel' button in the HTML page which will redirect to php file with the below code, my excel is not getting downloaded. Can someone tell me where the error is and what modification needs to be made. Tell me in the simplest way possible.

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");
     if(isset($_POST["export"]))
 {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cruddatabase");  
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
    fputcsv($output, array('ID Company Name','Company Type','Name','Email','Contact Number','Anniversary Date','Organisation Name','Meeting','Timeline For Conversation','Currency','Card','Locations'));  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM crudtable WHERE adate >= '$fdate' AND adate <= '$tdate' ORDER BY adate DESC";  
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  
         fputcsv($output, $row);  
    }  
    fclose($output);  
}  
 ?>
```

Comment: Which error do you have? A tip for export in excel with 90% of function is use [PHPspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Actually when clicking on the 'Export to Excel' button on the HTML page, my excel file is not getting downloaded. I am not able to locate the error in the above code.

Comment: Maybe you should make sure to put the header at the top of the <?php , did you try that?

Comment: Yeah it's there in the code. Can you check if the select query is right or not?

Comment: What I meant is, put the "header" at the very top of the php file, like so:

<?php  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

Comment: Also change this:

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  

to this:

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

Comment: Let me check if this works.

Comment: No, that did not work. As for the header, yes they are present in the above code. Check line numbers 6 and 7.

Comment: suppose that all the other things like connection , query and data composition are woorking you can maybe use at the end :     readfile($output);